# Gerar conteúdo dinamicamente com observable único

Tags: angular

Crio uma tabela dinamicamente (ngFor), conforme retorno de uma lista recuperada da base de dados (via API).

A tabela exibe informações de itens e quando o item possui anexo(s), na linha do item é criado um comando capaz de dar um get no servidor para trazer a relação de anexos desse item.

Esse comando "por trás dos panos" é um Observable que aguarda o retorno da lista de anexos para exibir na tela.

Meu problema: para cada item que possui anexo, ao criar o componente HTML associado ao Observable, estou criando várias instâncias desse mesmo Observable, se aciono o comando para traze a relação de anexos, todos os observables recebem a informação recuperada.

Eis abaixo um [código mínimo](https://plnkr.co/edit/0B5XtB?p=preview) para exemplo (questões comerciais não posso exibir o fonte na íntegra) (**Editado**: clica no link pra ver um código de exemplo)

```
<table>
<thead>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th>Item</th>
  <th>Anexo</th>
</thead>
<tbody *ngFor="let item of listItens">
  <tr>
    <td>{{ item.Id }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.Descricao }}</td>
    <td><a *ngIf="item.PossuiAnexo"/></td> //somente crio o comando se possui anexo
  </tr>
  <tr *ngIf="item.PossuiAnexo">Aqui tem um componente associado a um Observable que dá get no servidor e recupera a lista dos anexos se link for "clicado" </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Print das requisições. Cada uma delas correponde ao "observable" de cada item que contem anexo.
Preciso recuperar os dados somente no observable do item cujo comando foi acionado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: posta seu codigo

Comment: Eu tinha incluído um código aqui mas desapareceu. Vou tentar incluir novamente

Comment: Quero ressaltar que não existe erro de código, funciona. Meu problema é que quando crio o <tr> que contém o componente que vai exibir o resultado do Observable, todos os itens que tem anexo recebem o resultado, não somente no item cujo comando foi acionado.

Comment: Acho que se postasse o seu TS com os códigos referentes a questão, seria mais fácil de compreendermos.

Comment: Vou tentar criar um JSFiddler para melhor compor a pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se entendi bem, mas me parece que há uma certa confusão de conceitos. Ao clicar em "tem anexo", a função `onClickAnexo()` deveria ser responsável por buscar os anexos apenas daquele item específico. Para isso, seria importante indicar qual foi o item clicado:

```
<tbody  *ngFor="let iten of listItens; let i = index">
      <tr>
        <td>{{ iten.Id }}</td>
        <td>{{ iten.Desc }}</td>
        <td><a *ngIf="iten.Flag" 
              class="btn btn-primary"
              href="{{'#docTramite' + i}}" 
              id="{{ iten.Id }}"
              role="button" 
              aria-expanded="false"
              (click)="onClickAnexo($event)">Tem anexo</a></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
            <div class="row" [hidden]="isHidden" 
              style="background: yellow;">
                <div class="collapse" id="{{'docTramite'+ i}}">
                  <div class="card card-body">
                    <span>Recupero a lista de anexos aqui </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

E no component:

```
  listAnexos = [];

  onClickAnexo(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id);
    //Faz a busca no backend, baseado no Id clicado
    //Armazena o resultado em listAnexos na posição do id
    this.listAnexos[event.target.id] = "resultado";
    console.log(this.isHidden);
  }
```

Por fim, garanta que somente o elemento que tiver recebido o anexo será apresentado:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">
    <div class="row"
      style="background: yellow;" *ngIf="listAnexos[iten.Id]">
        <div id="{{'docTramite'+ i}}">
          <div class="card card-body">
            <span>Recupero a lista de anexos aqui </span>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

[Aqui o link com as alterações](https://plnkr.co/edit/9JAo4O2gYeIxOVsEZKlg?p=preview).

Comment: Olá vou avaliar a sugestão! Obrigada por colaborar!